# React onChange: Can I make a handleChange for many onChange events, and also pass an object key as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, onchange

**SOLUTION**

```
const onChangeHandler = (e, name) => {
  setFormData((c) => ({
    ...c,
    [name]: e.target.value,
  }));
};

onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler(e, "firstName")}
```

**OLD**

I have this function inside some inputs. There are like 15 inputs. I was wondering if I could wrap them up in a function and handle them all together. My individual input onChange handler is the following:

```
onChange={({ target }) =>
  setFormData((c) => ({
    ...c,
    driversLicense: target.value,
  }))
}
```

setFormData is passed from another component as props. Takes the previous value (c) and adds our current value. I would like a function to set dynamically **the key and the target**. So something like that, but I can't even reach the name. It says that it's not used. Any ideas?

```
const onChangeHandler = (e, name) => {
  setFormData((c) => ({
    ...c,
    name: e.target.value,
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `{ [propertyNameFromVariable]: value` }:

```
const onChangeHandler = (e, name) => {
  setFormData((c) => ({
    ...c,
    [name]: e.target.value,
  }));
};
```

(The next question would be: how do we memorize this with useMemo/useCallback?)